# SystemConfiguration reachPerformAndUnlock crash

Tags: ios, xcode

I keep getting this crash in Fabric since the launch of iOS 11 and I have no idea what is causing it.
This is the stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180d78910 objc_msgSend + 16
1  SystemConfiguration            0x1828fd644 reachPerformAndUnlock + 540
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181b53404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181b52c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181b5079c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
5  CoreFoundation                 0x181a70da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
6  GraphicsServices               0x183a53020 GSEventRunModal + 100
7  UIKit                          0x18ba5178c UIApplicationMain + 236
8  App                            0x102923e90 main (main.m:14)
9  libdyld.dylib                  0x181501fc0 start + 4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I got this exact stack trace from Firebase Crashlytics now.. Did you ever figure it out? I suspect it's because some previously allocated memory has been deallocated when the app was in the background, and when the user attempts to open the app again, it crashes when trying to "wake up", so it performs a hard restart. At least, that's what I hope.. We have no reports of visible crashes..

Comment: Did you got solution for this crash?

Comment: Any solution for this?